# Hg backout, then take the changes and store on a branch

Tags: mercurial

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a commit to the default branch that I need off default. We build for production from default and this commit is not ready. So I have used hg backout to undo the changes from the default branch. Now I have created a new branch to store the changes. But when I attempt to transplant or graft the changes onto the branch I get told that I cannot graft in changes from an ancestor. This makes sense, but I need to pull changes from an ancestor, how do I do this.

I have tried

```
hg diff -c 8c13fc133926 > new_branch.diff
hg import new_branch.diff
```

but this Fails with no explanation. Any pointers?

**EDIT**

It seems I'm a little hard to follow, so I will try and clarify.

```
o Default with only ready changes
|
| o Not ready changes (new commit on a branch)
| | 
|/
o   Hg backout commit Undoing not ready changes from default
| 
o   Lots of other commits and merges to default
| 
o   ...
| 
o   Not ready changes (original commit)
```

The graph above shows where I need to get to. 
I have done this by using `hg diff -c 6877 | patch -p1` where 6877 is the revision of the commit that needs to be moved off of default.

But I think I am doing this wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your new branch off of the revision **BEFORE** you made the "not ready changes" commit.  I will call that revision 123:

```
hg up 123
hg branch NewBranch
hg ci -m "branching for NewBranch"
```

Now you can do your **GRAFT**, with no concerns about ancestors.

Tying up loose ends:

It seems that you'll already have another head on `NewBranch`, the one you said you created.  You can merge with that or just close it.  You can see the heads with:

```
hg heads NewBranch
```

I will call that unwanted head revision 456.  And I would close it like this:

```
hg up 456
hg ci --close-branch -m "It was all just a dream... a terrible, terrible dream."
```

Which reminds me: you could have used the same technique (closing an unwanted branch head) instead of `hg backout`!  Then you could have done the steps above ... except you'd be able to do a neat-and-tidy REBASE ("leaving no witnesses", like they say in the movies) instead of cherry-picking with GRAFT, and leaving behind the wreckage on the default branch!

Comment: We make no changes to the history once pushed to the main repo. So backout was the only option.

Comment: That's cool.  I'm glad you mentioned this (the fact that you had already pushed to the main repo) because it makes an important point: once you've pushed some history to another repo, you won't be allowed to graft or rebase (assuming the "phase" system is working).

Answer (score 2):

I personally avoid grafting as much as possible, and your commit is already in the history. You seem to be using the correct commands, but it is hard to understand your issue, more information is needed.

How about creating your new branch from the commit that you wanted to backout?

```
  o    NewBranch: head, creation of the branch
  |
  |
o |    default: head, Backed-out changeset
| |
|/
o      default: commit (not ready)
|
|
o      default: initial state
|
```

Another idea, if you don't care about grafting, simply start your new branch from the `initial state`, and transplant the commit; it won't be considered an ancestor anymore.

```
    o    NewBranch: head, grafted commit
    |
   /|
  | o    NewBranch: creation
  | |
  | |
o | |    default: Backed-out changeset
| | |
|/  |
o  /     default: commit (not ready)
| / 
|/
o        default: initial state
|
```

Comment: Awesome illustrations!